# Why is knock sensor tripping "check engine" light but only on warm-up (10 min/1 mi)

Tags: honda, electronic-control-module, pilot, warmup, knock-sensor

2011 Honda Pilot 4WD shows P0325 code but only until the car warms up (10 mins/1 mile). Reset with OBDII the code does NOT come back on. 87 octane gas from many stations in a 50 mile radius. Code does not come on under load or up an incline after warm-up but once cooled down will trip again. Not a problem if you keep an OBDII in the car and reset it once every start-up but would like to know the cause. Lean air/fuel ratio before warm up, ECU to knock sensor problem, harness wires are good and no other mechanical problems noted. Crazy as it sounds I've got a 2006 Toyota Tundra that is doing exactly the same thing. 4.7l engine that uses 93 octane at all times. Have not seen this problem in any forum or on YouTube but I've got 2 vehicles doing the exact same thing. Computer diagnostics is $$$ and repair on both requires removing the intake manifold...also $$$.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! My bet would be, the knock sensor is bad while the engine is cold, then when it heats up, something inside of the knock sensor reconnects and starts working. I have no clue how you would go about testing it. While I don't recommend remove/replace wrenching, it might just be the easiest/cheapest way to go in this case.

Comment: There's one vehicle make/model that triggered the knock sensor error code. It wasn't the sensor or wiring since replacing it the error code reappeared no matter how often manual resets were performed. It was a worn out spring loaded belt tensioner hitting its end stop with the tell tale visual of the drive belt flopping at idle rpm. In another case, a replacement drive belt was longer than original and allowed the spring loaded belt tensioner to hit its end stop. Both situations created mechanical knocking detected by the knock sensor,

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I've ordered OEM replacement of the knock sensor the wiring harness and new gaskets. $100 and about 3 hours of my time. The timing belt is due to be changed but I think I'll leave that to my mechanic. Have a Merry Christmas guys and thanks again for the input.